# Adjustable dates for correlations matrix not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am building a dynamic correlations table that is capable of selecting data from a specific date range.  The matrix is going to be used for determining the relationships between the prices of different commodities and is sourced from a dataset of monthly price data spanning multiple years.  Below is a screenshot of the correlations matrix for all data in the data set:

[image: Correlations matrix]

Which is stored in a sheet named CMO-Historical-Data-Monthly.

And here is a screenshot of the source data:

[image: Source data for correlations matrix]

Here is the correlation formula that's used in every cell with absolute column cell reference for the base commodity and a dynamic one for the commodity it is being compared with:

=CORREL('CMO-Historical-Data-Monthly'!$B$2:$B$769,'CMO-Historical-Data-Monthly'!E$2:E$769)

Which makes it possible to easily apply the formula to all cells in the matrix.

Here is the formula I wrote for making the correlations data look at a dynamic date range:

=CORREL(INDEX('CMO-Historical-Data-Monthly'!$B$2:$B$769,MATCH($C$2,'CMO-Historical-Data-Monthly'!$A$2:$A$769,0)):INDEX('CMO-Historical-Data-Monthly'!$B$2:$B$769,MATCH($C$3,'CMO-Historical-Data-Monthly'!$A$2:$A$769,0)),INDEX('CMO-Historical-Data-Monthly'!B$2:B$769,MATCH($C$2,'CMO-Historical-Data-Monthly'!$A$2:$A$769,0)):INDEX('CMO-Historical-Data-Monthly'!B$2:B$769,MATCH($C$3,'CMO-Historical-Data-Monthly'!$A$2:$A$769,0)))

When I input that formula, attempt to drag it and change the date range for comparisons, or otherwise adjust the date range I get the following output:

[image: Output]

What I was expecting was something like the original correlations matrix but using the dates specified in cells C2 & C3.  How can I adjust the correlations formula so that it uses the dynamic dates but otherwise behaves the same as the formula used for making the original correlations matrix?

Comment: How are we to reproduce this using screenshots? You could use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to paste your data as a table in your question.

Comment: Tested it again and it turns out the equation does work, I just wasn't stretching it out far enough.  Thanks folks!